# why can't i apply armature on mesh?

Tags: armature, append

[![in pose mode with armature selected
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7OPg.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7OPg.jpg)i'm trying to make many version of the same figure by, having a armature and
setting it in different positions, and then making a new copy of both armature
and mesh and then apply them again. 
My årobkem here is, i have an armature and a mesh, and i can se the armature in edit mode, but i cant se it in object, neither apply it.
I dont understand why its not possible, and how i can solve it.
The armature seems to bee there, - why cant i find it and apply it to the mesh

regards Frank Fenriz[image: armature and mesh in edit mode][![lacking armature in object mode 
][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeFoV.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeFoV.jpg)[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to click on the armature for it to show in the upper right tab where you can select "Pose mode" and then rotate your mesh however you want (depending on the armature)

Comment: thanks Zombie Spale  - but it's not the problem.  I tried, and when doing as you sugested, the armature dont show up in the scene, - even that i have it selected over at the right panel. the same is both when being in pose mode or object mode. it only shows in edit mode